# Don't understand this piece of code ? It's about reading a file in c++

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, argv

I have a work to do in C++, and it's suppose to read a file .txt and use the informations inside. But our teacher gave us the beginning of the code to help up and I really don't get it. I'm a very beginner in c++ so I've been looking for it for hours, but I have'nt found the answer, thank you !

Here's the piece of code:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::ifstream* myfile = NULL;

    if (argc == 2) {
        file = myfile = new std::ifstream(argv[1]);
        if (myfile->fail())
            std::cerr << "Error at the opening of the file'" << argv[1] << "'" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "No file name." << std::endl;

    while (*file) {
        std::string event;
        *file >> event;
        if (!(*file)) break;

        if (event == "recipe") {
            std::string namerecipe;
            *file >> recipe;
```

...

Soo I don't get it ? What is *file ? and file ? Is it a pointer on the file ? Why doesn't any function like get line work on it ? Why is "while *file" supposed to do ?
Thank you very much !

Comment: Do you know what pointers are?

Comment: I suspect this code is deliberately insane.

Comment: Wait. Your teacher allocates `std::ifstream` dynamically? Either I have missed something, or there is a special teaching purpose, or the teacher is not good at programming.

Comment: @NickyC I think this is being done to get a pointer for `file` which must be defined elsewhere. Since `std::ifstream myfile(argv[1]); file = &myfile;` is a lot simpler and most likely safer, you're probably right. The teacher is obfuscating or not that good with C++. Can't call them a bad programmer, though. Maybe they're a genius with Java or LISP.

Comment: @immibis no sorry, that's all I have..

Comment: @user4581301 haha I really believed I was just stupid and thank you for y your answer

Comment: @user4581301 "I think this is being done to get a pointer for `file`" - you're missing the point, why should `file` be a pointer?

Comment: I'm not missing that point.It shouldn't be a pointer. I can understand an instructor using it as a misguided lesson just like I can understand why people drink and drive while I still think it's really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
```

A typical function entry point.

```
    std::ifstream* myfile = NULL;

    if (argc == 2) {
```

Make sure that there are enough arguments to get a file name from `argv[1]`.

```
        file = myfile = new std::ifstream(argv[1]);
```

Dynamically allocates a file input stream and tries to use it to open the file specified in `argv[1]`. This file stream is then assigned to two pointers, `file` and `myfile`. I admit to not seeing the point to having two pointers, but I also don't see the point of a pointer in the first place.

```
        if (myfile->fail())
```

Calls the stream's `fail` function. This tests if there is anything wrong with the stream. At this point all there is to test is whether or not the stream opened.

```
            std::cerr << "Error at the opening of the file'" << argv[1] << "'" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "No file name." << std::endl;

    while (*file) {
```

Dereferences the `file` pointer to operate on the file object. This will have the effect of calling the stream's boolean operator. This has either the same (C++11 or more recent) or so similar as to not matter in this case (previous to C++11) effect as calling `!file->fail()`. More on operator bool here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

```
        std::string event;
        *file >> event;
```

Read one whitespace-delimited token, a single word, from the stream.

```
        if (!(*file)) break;
```

Operator bool again. Exit the loop on failure.

```
        if (event == "recipe") {
            std::string namerecipe;
            *file >> recipe;
```

Read another word from the stream.

The code could be re-written along these lines:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    if (argc == 2) 
    {
        std::ifstream myfile(argv[1]);
        if (myfile)
        {
            std::string event;
            while (myfile >> event) 
            {
                //this function is getting deep. Consider spinning this off into a new function
                if (event == "recipe") 
                {
                    std::string namerecipe;
                    if (myfile >> recipe)
                    {
                        // do stuff that is missing from code sample
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // handle error
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Error at the opening of the file'" << argv[1] << "'" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "No file name." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate you helping me ! I think I got now, Your explanations are very clear

Answer (score 0):

1. `*file` is your pointer that is pointing to an Input File Stream `ifstream` object.
2. `file` is your Input File Stream `ifstream` object.
3. `while(*file)` is using the stream's boolean operator to test for an error condition in the Input File Stream (while reading the file with no errors)

Comment: Point 3 is incorrect. It's not testing for NULL, it's using the stream's boolean operator to test for an error condition in the stream.

Comment: @user4581301 I thought it is like how we iterate a linked list. Ehm thanks for the lesson I will edit it. Can you clarify more?

Comment: it's shorthand for `while (!file->fail())`. More here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool (I should correct. In C++11 it is shorthand. Previously it was only similar)

Comment: After a re-read, 1 and 2 can be read with the reverse of your intent. Interpreting as code, `*file` is the `ifstream` and `file` is the pointer to the `ifstream`.

Comment: @FirstStep Thank you very much for answering, I will try to work with these informations !